# ¿como mostrar varios datos en un label de charts.js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chart.js

en un label deseo poner la fechas que me traiga lo que recibio php...el problema es que solo me muestra una fecha y no me recorre todas las fechas en label..

**CODIGO**

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'api/graficos_ventas.php',
                data: {'fechainicio' : fechinicio, 'fechafinal' : fechfinal},
                success: function(data){
                    var valores = JSON.parse(data);

                    var Datos = {
                                    labels : [for (var i = valores.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
                                                {
                                                    valores[i].fechfactura;
                                                },],
                                    datasets : [
                                        {
                                            fillColor : 'rgba(91,228,146,0.6)', //COLOR DE LAS BARRAS
                                            strokeColor : 'rgba(57,194,112,0.7)', //COLOR DEL BORDE DE LAS BARRAS
                                            highlightFill : 'rgba(73,206,180,0.6)', //COLOR "HOVER" DE LAS BARRAS
                                            highlightStroke : 'rgba(66,196,157,0.7)', //COLOR "HOVER" DEL BORDE DE LAS BARRAS
                                            data : [valores]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }

                            var contexto = document.getElementById('grafico').getContext('2d');
                            window.Barra = new Chart(contexto).Bar(Datos, { responsive : true });
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
```

Intente hacer un for dentro del label para que me mostrara todas las fecha pero no me funciono, agradecería el interés de como puedo solucionar ese detalle.

Comment: Hola Daniel. Puedes poner el error que mencionas?

Answer (score 2):

Tu código contiene errores graves que hacen que no funcione. Y esos errores se pueden ver fácilmente en la consola de JavaScript. Mi recomendación sería que aprendieses a usarla porque te va a ahorrar mucho tiempo y te va a hacer un mejor desarrollador.

Ejecutando el código que tienes puedes ver que el problema está en esta parte:

```
....
labels : [for (var i = valores.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
            {
                valores[i].fechfactura;
            },],
....
```

Donde en la consola de JavaScript se muestra el siguiente error de sintaxis:

> Unexpected token for

Es decir, no se puede tener un bucle `for` en ese sitio (dentro de la definición de un array). Una solución sencilla: crea el valor del array con el bucle `for` fuera de la definición y luego simplemente asígnalo donde corresponda. Algo como esto:

```
....
success: function(data){
    var valores = JSON.parse(data);

    // crea el valor del array fuera de la definición
    var valorLabels = [];
    for (var i = valores.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)  {
        valorLabels[i] = valores[i].fechfactura;
    }

    var Datos = {
                    labels : valorLabels,
    ....
```

---

Otro error con el que te vas a encontrar más adelante: `data : [valores]`; La variable `valores` ya es un array, no necesitas hacer `[valores]`, esa línea debería ser `data: valores`

Comment: Hola @Alvaro Montoro tu codigo me ha servido, muchas gracias..tengo una duda he estado haciendo pruebas pero no me sale, si quiero recorrer los valores tambien, deberia de hacer otro ciclo con diferente variable?

Comment: @JDavid hola amigo pudistes recorrer en un solo el for para mostrar todos los campos o te toco que hacer otro for?

Answer (score 1):

Solo es necesario mapear el vector o json así:

```
...
labels : [valores.map((el) =>el.fechfactura)],
...
```

Si imprimes eso el mismo, recorre el vector y extrae los datos.
Lo cual es mas recomendable no es necesario de hacer un for, que se veria un poco menos practico.